# store foreign key or varchar value

Tags: mysql

I have multiple tables through my site:

Is it best to store the foreign key from the lookup table or the `varchar` itself.

Two of my site tables are

```
job_profile
    id
    title
    salary_range_seeking
    cv_link
    datetime_created
    job_type

job_type
    id
    type
```

`job type`- `type` values are `Full Time`, `Part Time`

So for example is it best to store the id from `job_type` in the column `job_type` and maintain referential integrity or have it so on the front end the user picks the value and the text value is stored in the column `job_type`. I am looking for the best performance option and recommended practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll get better performance using a foreign key instead of storing the text value in a field, because it'll reduce the amount of memory used.

This is the recommended practice when the value of the field (in this case job_type) is  going to be repeated with a high rate.

Comment: if the value is not always required would i need to allow null on the field as i have read this is not best practice

Comment: will i get a better performance if i need to do joins though.

Comment: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/85-Why-NULL-Values-Should-Not-Be-Used-in-a-Database-Unless-Required.htm and on other sites online.

Comment: To reduce this i have created join tables in certain instances with a unique contraint on one side(one to many) instead of adding values with joins and allow nulls, i.e. if i had an event table and a business table. A event may be created by a business but not always rather than add business_id to event i thought and have read it is best practice to not allow null values and instead have a joining table so a joining table would be business_event with business_id and event_id and event_id would be unique(one to many)

Comment: That blog entry is specifically referring to null values in string fields. With your design, null values in an FK field are totally legit.

Comment: Your example of event/business relationship is a case of over-normalization. It looks good on paper and in the class-room, but in real life it's just not necessary to get that normalized. You're throwing in extra joins for no benefit.

Comment: In my opinion in this the performance will be better doing a join instead of storing the texts "Full Time" and "Part Time" repeatedly (using a Tinyint instead of a varchar). It will reduce disk usage, memory consumption, and queries will execute faster. On the other side if the tables are not big enough you'll not get great benefits.

Comment: I recommend you the book "High Performance MySQL" by Baron Schwartz, Peter Zaitsev and Vadim Tkachenko. It explains how MySQL do these tasks and why in this case the JOIN solution would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Performance for reads or writes? or running reports? How you store data depends a lot on what you intend to do with it, and how you intend to do it.

Now, it is generally accepted to store the id, not the varchar, there are several reasons for this, but the primary one is that it's the generally accepted way of doing it. This will make support for your work easier in the future for other people, and probably for you too. With the basic layout you are providing there should be almost no impact to performance regardless of what you are using this data for.

If the primary purpose of the `job_profile` table is to run reports off of it, you get better performance by storing the varchar and not needing to do a join. This type of de-normalizing you would normally see in a data warehouse type of application where you make trade offs on using more memory and storage for faster retrieval and presentation of data.

Comment: if the field is optional is it best to store the varchar- i.e. if not every job has a type. Or is it best to have a foreign key constraint and allow null.

Comment: I would have an FK constraint and allow null. Just remember, you would want to do left joins to the `job_type` table if you allow nulls, as inner joins would only return results that have non-null values.